# Setting ignore for Joomla files or directories

Tags: development, templates

I'm new to developing in Joomla and I was wondering if there are a set bunch of files and directories you ignore say for example using the VSCode ftp extension or .gitignore.

I'm specifically looking at developing templates and modules locally then uploading to a staging server and/or Git repo.

I have this these to ignore in VSCode ftp extension settings:

"ignore": [
".vscode",
".htaccess",
"configuration.php",
"administrator",
"tmp",
"cache",
"logs",
"images",
"media",
"plugins",
"components",
"language",
"layouts",
"templates/cassiopeia"

Cheers,
Tim

Answer (score 1):

The way I work is to have separate git repos for each extension I'm developing and use symlinks to bring them into my local development site rather than having the entire site in a repo. For me it helps keep everything compartmentalised and easier to manage.

I routinely ignore any files not used by the extension like .DS_Store or .idea, plus any zip or text files. I often keep reference notes on text files for my own use so they don't need including.

We use Gantry for our templates, but we have quite a custom set-up so the way we do that is probably not going to be much help to you.

Comment: Thanks Grant that's helpful. It's interesting to know how other's develop with Joomla. I'm just feeling my way around at the moment so things like this are useful in helping me get my stack/workflow together. I don't want to store anything in a repo that doesn't need to be there as part of a what I'm developing and also in the local files that show in VSCode.

Comment: I also didn't know about Gantry, it looks very interesting. I'm going to give it a proper look :)

Comment: Yep, worth a look. It's perfect for what we use it for, but it is effectively its own framework within the Joomla framework. 

We have two Git repos for our Gantry. Most of the template folders and files go into one repo so we can use that same template on multiple sites, but the individual page template yaml files for an individual site are stored in one particular folder so that has its own separate repo. if that makes sense. It means the initial symlinking is a bit of a task but once it's done you're good to go.

Comment: Cool, sound sgreat. I also like that you can use Twig with it too! Thanks.